# Mathematica Giving Me Trouble

Tags: calculus, mathematica

I'm new to mathematica and am just learning the basics.  I've run into a few things that I can't figure out.

The first is this:

"Number 11"

> $$r[t\_] := \{(1/3)*(t^3), 0.5 * t^2, t\}$$

(*Unit Tangent Vector = $r'/\text{Length}(r')$ *)

> $$ta = \frac{r'[t]}{\text{Norm}[r'[t]]}$$

(* Unit Normal Vector = $ta'$/Length($ta'$) *)

> $$n = \frac{ta'[t]}{\text{Norm}[ta'[t]]}$$

(* Curvature = Length($ta'$)/Length($r'[t]$) *)

> $$c = \frac{Norm[ta'[t]]}{\text{Norm}[r'[t]]}$$

"Number 11"

> $$\{t^2/Sqrt[1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4], (1. t)/Sqrt[1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4], 1/Sqrt[1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4]\}$$

.

> Derivative[
>     1][{t^2/Sqrt[1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4], (1. t)/Sqrt[
>      1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4], 1/Sqrt[1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4]}][
>     t]/Norm[Derivative[
>      1][{t^2/Sqrt[1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4], (1. t)/Sqrt[
>       1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4], 1/Sqrt[1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4]}][
>      t]]
>   .
>   Norm[Derivative[
>      1][{t^2/Sqrt[1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4], (1. t)/Sqrt[
>       1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4], 1/Sqrt[1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4]}][
>      t]]/(Sqrt[1 + 1. Abs[t]^2 + Abs[t]^4])

I'm not sure how to make it look nice on the forums here sorry.  But it's not evaluating the Norm or derivative at some places.  It also has a lot of Abs which I don't know if they are totally necessary.  How can I get this to to work?

The second one is a problem with taking derivatives.

> In[217]:= f[x_, y_, z_] := ((x^2)*(y^3)) + (z^4)
>
> fx = Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, z]
>
> fy = Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, y, z]
>
> fz = Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x, y, z]
>
> x1[p_] := p + (3*(p^2))
>
> dxdp = Derivative[1][x1][p]
>
> y1[p_] := p*(E^p)
>
> dydp = Derivative[1][x1][p]
>
> z1[p_] := p*Sin[p]
>
> dzdp = Derivative[1][x1][p]
>
> Print["dF/dP:"]
>
> Print[(fx*dxdp) + (fy*dydp) + (fz + dzdp)]

The result:

> Out[218]= 32 Sin[t] Sin[2 t]^3
>
> Out[219]= 48 Sin[t]^2 Sin[2 t]^2
>
> Out[220]= 32 Sin[3 t]^3
>
> Out[222]= 1 + 6 p
>
> Out[224]= 1 + 6 p
>
> Out[226]= 1 + 6 p

During evaluation of In[217]:= dF/dP:

During evaluation of In[217]:= 1+6 p+48 (1+6 p) Sin[t]^2 Sin[2 t]^2+32 (1+6 p) Sin[t] Sin[2 t]^3+32 Sin[3 t]^3

Why am I getting Sins and t variables for a derivative of a xy function with no cos or sins?  This has happened on multiple problems for me.

Any and all help is welcome!
Thanks much!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: It might be better to ask this at [Mathematica.stackexchange.com](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). They want to you to preformat the input (it is easy to do with the input tools). Also, it is difficult to pair your Mathematica inputs and outputs, so I cannot quickly diagnose the problem. May be you have forgotten that Mathematica needs a space (or *) as a separator in a product. So for example it interprets `xy` as a variable totally unrelated to `x` and `y`. You need to write `x y` or `x*y` for it to understand your intention.

Comment: A bit clearer now. I didn't know that you can get derivatives with such calls - I only know of `D[f,x]` and such. Anyway, are you sure there aren't some lingering definitions for $x$ or $y$? I don't know exactly how it goes, but if you assigned $x$ a trig function earlier in the session, then that may stick.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

`r[t_]:={t^3/3,t^2/2,t}`
`ta[t_]:=Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]],Assumptions->Element[t,Reals]]`
`n[t_]:=Simplify[ta'[t]/Norm[ta'[t]],Assumptions->Element[t,Reals]]`
`c[t_]:=Simplify[Norm[ta'[t]]/Norm[r'[t]],Assumptions->Element[t,Reals]]`

Then
`ta[t]` gives
$$
\left\{\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^4+t^2+1}},\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^4+t^2+1}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^4+t^2+1}}\right\}
$$
and `n[t]` gives
$$
\small\left\{\frac{t \left(t^2+2\right)}{\sqrt{\left(t^4+t^2+1\right) \left(t^4+4
   t^2+1\right)}},\frac{1-t^4}{\sqrt{t^8+5 t^6+6 t^4+5 t^2+1}},-\frac{2
   t^3+t}{\sqrt{\left(t^4+t^2+1\right) \left(t^4+4 t^2+1\right)}}\right\}
$$
and `c[t]` gives
$$
\sqrt{\frac{t^4+4 t^2+1}{\left(t^4+t^2+1\right)^3}}
$$

---

If your variables have had values assigned to them, and have not been Cleared, those values will be used. For example, if I have set

`x=2Sin[t]`
`y=2Sin[2t]`
`z=2Sin[3t]`
`f[x_,y_,z_]:=((x^2)*(y^3))+(z^4)`

then

`Derivative[1,0,0][f][x,y,z]` returns $32 \sin (t) \sin ^3(2 t)$

`Derivative[0,1,0][f][x,y,z]` returns $48 \sin ^2(t) \sin ^2(2 t)$

`Derivative[0,0,1][f][x,y,z]` returns $32 \sin ^3(3 t)$

If I clear the variables with `Clear[x,y,z]`,

`Derivative[1,0,0][f][x,y,z]` returns $2 x y^3$

`Derivative[0,1,0][f][x,y,z]` returns $3 x^2 y^2$

`Derivative[0,0,1][f][x,y,z]` returns $4 z^3$